# WordPress Widgets no drop down

Tags: widgets

i gave my editor role an access to my Widget settings.
But i wonder why it is different when an admin access it.
It has no drop down.
see the attachment:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rv3g3.png
Thanks

Ivan

Comment: How did you give access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have accessibility mode enabled.  To get the regular arrow drop down disable accessibility mode through the screen options menu.

[image]